# Is Obi-Wan wearing the Skywalker lightsaber in the duel of Revenge of the Sith?

Tags: star-wars

While watching again, after a long time the duel between Obi-Wan and Anakin in the Revenge of the Sith, I noticed that, for some scene Obi-Wan seems to be using Anakin's lightsaber.

For instance, the following three images are extracted from three different, but *consecutive* scenes, the design of the saber handle looks quite different:

This clearly looks like Obi-Wan's
[image]

But just after:

[image]

This is even clearer here with the small thing going out of the handle:

[image]

Is that just actors taking the wrong prop while doing the scene or is there something I missed?

Also, please let me know if this is not in-topic.

Comment: 1st screenshot shows OWK's [3rd lightsaber](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Obi-Wan_Kenobi%27s_third_lightsaber) I believe. It's even [for sale](https://uncrate.com/obi-wans-revenge-of-the-sith-lightsaber/). Just missing the first 5 figures :)

Answer (score 1):

There's most probably (definately?) a miscue here. I have found no evidence whatsoever that somewhere, during the battle, or for any other reason, that they may have switched weapons. Either the actors wrongly grabbed the wrong prop, or the one in charge got confused.<sup>1</sup>

On this first screenshot, we see Obi-Wan Kenobi holding his [lightsaber](https://www.starwars.com/databank/obi-wan-kenobis-lightsabers):

[image: Obi-Wan Kenobi lightsaber]

This is his [third lightsaber](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Obi-Wan_Kenobi%27s_third_lightsaber) (see also [Obi-Wan Kenobi lightsaber](https://uncrate.com/obi-wans-revenge-of-the-sith-lightsaber/))

Now, I took another screenshot of the final duel. We see Anakin Skywalker holding his lightsaber:
[image: Anakin Skywalker lightsaber]

Now, this is his [second lightsaber](https://screenrant.com/anakin-skywalker-darth-vader-lightsabers-used/) ([first lightsaber](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Anakin_Skywalker%27s_first_lightsaber) was destroyed in the foundry)

**Problem**: on this screenshot, Obi-Wan Kenobi *is* holding Anakin Skywalker's.

[image: Obi-Wan Kenobi holding Anakin Skywalker's lightsaber]

---

<sup>1. I keep searching and will update if necessary.</sup>